# How to change from for to foreach in this case?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, foreach

In my Android App I have simple C-like 'for loops' like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++) {
  // I must use the value of 'i' in the for loop body

}
```

But the Android studio gives me a Lint warning, suggesting to change the for loop to a foreach loop.

Can you tell me how can I switch to foreach loop and use 'i' variable in the body of the loop?

Comment: You can't, you would have to maintain a separate counter.

Comment: is just a warning, you could [supress it](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings)

Comment: You would have to keep a separate counter outside the loop and just increment inside the loop.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the `warning`...

Comment: OK then, thanks for the comments, I'll go for suppressing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to make use of the counter variable within the loop, it doesn't make sense to switch to using a `for each` -- essentially, the linter may be wrong here.

If you do want to change it nevertheless, you need to define the counter outside the `for each` as follows:

```
int i = 0; // your counter, now defined outside of the loop -- but still usable inside
for ( SomeItem e : SomeIterableObj ) { // the for-each loop
    // do something with the element, 'e'
    // do something with the counter, 'i'
    i++; // or manipulate the counter in whichever way you need to.
}
```

This way, you're using a `for each` loop and you still get to make use of a counter.

Comment: ssh Answer is nice too. But this one seems more clear so I will accept as the right answer.

Comment: @Ehsan no problem. But i need to add a note : in this case you need check for equality of `SomeIterableObj` size and your real value.

Comment: @Ehsan right, make sure the value of `i` makes sense in the context of `SomeIterableObj.size()` (if that's how you were to access the iterable object's size, for example). `i` probably shouldn't exceed this value.

Answer (score 4):

`foreach` construction is not applicable to int.

`foreach` works only with arrays and collections.

For alternative you can use :

```
int max = 5;
int[] arr = new int[max];

for (int i : arr) {

}
```

[Docs](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) :

> The enhanced for-loop is a popular feature introduced with the Java SE platform in version 5.0. Its simple structure allows one to simplify code by presenting for-loops that visit each element of an array/collection without explicitly expressing how one goes from element to element.

Comment: Ok, then Lint blindly gives me warning. It seems I must suppress the warning. I vote your answer up. thanks.

Comment: @Ehsan your pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're iterating over an array, the foreach construct means you do not need an array index.

So, for example:

```
int[] myArrayValues = new int[4];

// code to fill up array ...

for (int specificValue : myArrayValues) {
    // specific value is a value from the array, do something useful with it
}
```

In this case, specificValue is equal to myArrayValues[0] on the first iteration through the loop, then myArrayValues[1], myArrayValues[2] and finally myArrayValues[3] as the loop iterates.

Notes that in the answer above, although there is a variable i, it's not an index at all and will contain the vales in the array (in that case, they're all 0 until the array is filled with values).

So, for example to sum the values in the array, we can do something like this:

```
int[] items = new int[3];
items[0] = 3;
items[1] = 6;
items[2] = 7;

int sum = 0;

for( int value : items ) {
    sum += value;
}

// at this point sum = 16
```

Think of it as "for each *value* in *items*"

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation.